# Select values from the same column

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a database related question for WordPress.

My table is represented as follows:

**ID | customID | column1 | column2**

```
1      8      _item    item number

2      8      _price    item price

3      9      _item    item number

4      9      _price    item price
```

I want to retrieve the following rows using a MySQL `SELECT` statement:

**CustomID | _price | _item |**

```
8       item price(from col2)    item number(from col2)
9       item price(from col2)    item number(from col2)
```

Is this possible? The value `_price` and `_item` should be shown as columns with values from column2. How to solve this?

Comment: How do you know when its an item number or an item price? Does the data literally say item number/item price? Or is the data like Item Number: Z123 and Item Price: $3.35?

Comment: ye *item number* and *item price* are values for each product.  _price and _item are literally _price and _item.  I'll try @LSA solution as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

Your tables are designed quite badly. You should build an extra table which maps product and price. However this is what you can do with your solution:

```
Select t1.customID, t1.column2, t2.column2 from <tablename> t1,
 <tablename> t2 
 where t1.customID = t2.customId 
 and t1.column1 like '_item' 
 and t2.column1 like '_price';
```